# Send JSON from log4js to logstash and fields

Tags: json, logging, logstash, log4js-node

I'm using [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) to log my application and I'd like to send logs to logstash.

Here is a defalt appender for log4js [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638677/433685):

```
 "appenders": [
    {
      "type": "console"
    },
    {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 5000,
      "type": "logstashUDP"
    }
  ]
```

and here is the logstash configuration file:

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  stdout {}
}
```

Sending logs works correctly but I'm sending JSON log and in logstash I see a field for each charachter of the json.

> 2016-07-01T10:29:36.161Z 127.0.0.1
>   {"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-07-01T10:29:36.160Z","message":"My
>   message...","fields":{"0":"{","1":"\n","2":" ","3":" ","4":"\"", ...

I'm new to logstash but I like to group all fields in a big string. How can I do it?

Comment: you might need to use codec => "json" in your udp to tell it that the incoming logs are json logs. The default is plain

Comment: @pandaadb Ok, thanks, if you can add it as answer I'll check it as accepted otherway I'll delete the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order for your input to know that it is json, you will need to add a codec to it:

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => "json"
    codec => "json"
  }
}
```

Regards,

Artur