# How to use log4js to send logs to elasticsearch?

Tags: log4js-node, log4javascript

I have a node app running as a server and trying to send logs to the remote elasticsearch.

It looks like some syntax has been changed in the recent version of log4js. I tried one example from the link but it errors out. 
[How to log from Node.js with Express to ELK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638545/how-to-log-from-node-js-with-express-to-elk)

How do we configure the elasticsearch in the recent version of log4js v5.2.2?

Comment: Hi jtheg, welcome to stackoverflow. To get more valuable answers to your question, please consider adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including your source code and the specific things you have tried that aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Following the doc worked for me to connect to the elasticsearch

https://github.com/log4js-node/logstashHTTP